# Windows Phone Binding Lost when setting new object

Tags: binding, windows-phone-8

Upon launch my app loads data from an xml file for the UI. The problem I am facing is the UI loads before my data and when the source is updated the binding for the UI is lost.

If I load the data in the constructor for my main page before setting the datacontext binding it works but the UI is frozen while this completes

```
            Stream readStream = await localFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("queue.xml");
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(readStream))
            {
                {
                    App.ViewModel.Queue = xs2.Deserialize(rd) as ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>;
                    rd.Close();
                }
            }
```

If I load this in a background worker it is smooth and the UI is not frozen but the App.Viewmodel.Queue gets assigned to the Deserialized object and then the UI binding is lost from the original object.

Can I somehow have the binding automatically update to the new object? This load function is from an outside class so I cannot reset the item source once its loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raising `PropertyChanged` event upon `Queue` property set will make UI control bound to `Queue` updated automatically via data-binding mechanism. Following is an example on how to raise the event :

```
private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _queue;
public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Queue 
{
    get
    {
        return _queue;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _queue)
        {
            _queue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Queue");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out something that works in my case. It's not necessarily the most elegant but it gets the job done.

I set the default Opacity of the WebBrowser to 0. Then, I attach an event handler for the LoadCompleted event:

```
private void browser_Post_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    browser_Post.Opacity = 1;
}
```

Now, before I load a new HTML page, I set the Opacity back to 0 so it hides the browser while the new HTML is being rendered so there is no flickering of backgrounds. When the HTML is finished loading the event will fire and the new HTML page will be shown as expected.